# How to make a custom Rotated Container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to make something similar to the spotify search custom container in flutter (Find attached screenshot) but can't quiet do it well. Any suggestions? I am still learning flutter[image: Spotify Container]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just `Transform` widget?

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(math.pi / 6),
  child: YourContainer(),
)
```

or

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

Transform(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(math.pi / 6),
  child: Image.asset('assets/images/pic.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
)
```